# Why does Location=emptystring occupy two rows on "GROUP BY Location" on a data.stackexchange query?

Tags: sql, data.stackexchange.com

Why does Location=emptystring occupy two rows on this data.stackexchange query? https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1627756/test

```
SELECT 
SUM(Reputation) AS rep,
Location
FROM Users
GROUP BY Location
ORDER BY rep DESC
```

[image]

Comment: NULL vs empty string. (I'd consider having a constraint to avoid empty strings.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this verison you'll see Location has both blank string and `null` values

```
SELECT SUM(Reputation) AS rep, 
  Location, 
  IIF(location is null, 1, 0) NullLocation
FROM Users
GROUP BY Location, iif(location is null, 1, 0)
ORDER BY rep DESC;
```

You can `IsNull / Coalesce` to sum both together:

```
SELECT SUM(Reputation) AS rep, 
  ISNULL(Location, '') Location
FROM Users
GROUP BY isnull(Location, '')
ORDER BY rep DESC;
```